# How to resolve automatic return type C++ - continuation

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

The following code is compiling on gcc only when I comment the method dotProduct(It source, const size_t size), but I need to fix it somehow so that it compiles with this method uncommented. The names of methods must stay same as my intention is automatic detection of return types. Can someone please help me how to mend the code to make it compile?

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iterator> 
#include <iostream>  
#include <limits>

using std::cerr; 

   //! Template IF predicate implementation
  template <bool B, typename TrueResult, typename FalseResult> 
  class TemplateIf {
  public:
    //! The result of template IF predicate
    typedef TrueResult Result;
  };

  //! Template IF predicate implementation - specialization for false condition
  template <typename TrueResult, typename FalseResult>
  class TemplateIf<false, TrueResult, FalseResult> {
  public:
    //! The result of template IF predicate
    typedef FalseResult Result;
  };


  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  class DetermineComputationType {
  public:
    //! The determined result type
    // If (isSpecialized(T1) && isSpecialized(T2)) {
    typedef typename TemplateIf< std::numeric_limits<T1>::is_specialized && std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_specialized,
      // If (! isInteger(T1) && isInteger(T2) )
      //   return T1;
      typename TemplateIf< ! std::numeric_limits<T1>::is_integer && std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_integer, T1,
      // Else if (! isInteger(T2) && isInteger(T1) )
      //   return T2;
      typename TemplateIf< ! std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_integer && std::numeric_limits<T1>::is_integer, T2,
      // Else if ( sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2) )
      //   return T1;
      typename TemplateIf< (sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)), T1,
      // Else if ( sizeof(T2) > sizeof(T1) )
      //   return T2;
      typename TemplateIf< (sizeof(T2) > sizeof(T1)), T2,
      // Else if ( isSigned(T2) )
      //   return T1;
      // Else
      //   return T2; 
      // }
      typename TemplateIf< std::numeric_limits<T2>::is_signed, T1, T2>::Result >::Result >::Result >::Result >::Result,
      // Else if ( sizeof(T2> > sizeof(T1) )
      //   return T2;
      // Else
      //   return T1;
      typename TemplateIf< (sizeof(T2) > sizeof(T1)), T2, T1 >::Result >::Result Result;
  };


template <typename It1,typename It2> struct DotProduct 
{   
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It1>::value_type VT1;   
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It2>::value_type VT2;   
  typedef typename DetermineComputationType<VT1,VT2>::Result Result;
};  

  template <typename R, typename Ct, typename It>
  inline R dotProductRCtIt(It source, const size_t size)
  {
    Ct result = Ct();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      result += static_cast<Ct>(source[i]) * static_cast<Ct>(source[i]);

    return static_cast<R>(result);
  }

 //! For description see cpputil::dotProduct()
  template <typename R, typename Ct, typename It, typename It2>
  inline R dotProductRCtItIt2(It source, It2 source2, const size_t size) {
    Ct result = Ct();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      result += static_cast<Ct>(source[i]) * static_cast<Ct>(source2[i]);

    return static_cast<R>(result);
  }

template <typename T>
struct DetermineSingleType {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type Result;
};

//! Convenience method - see above for description
// !!! COMMENT THIS METHOD AND IT WILL START WORKING !!!
template <typename It> 
inline typename DetermineSingleType<It>::Result  dotProduct(It source, const size_t size) {
  typedef typename DetermineSingleType<It>::Result ItType;

  return dotProductRCtIt<ItType, ItType, It>(source, size);
}

template<typename Result,typename It, typename It2> Result dotProduct(It source1, It2 source2, const size_t size) 
{
  //typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type ItType;
  //typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It2>::value_type It2Type;
  //typedef typename DetermineComputationType<Result, ItType>::Result Ct;
 typedef typename DotProduct<It, It2>::Result Ct;

  return dotProductRCtItIt2<Result, Ct, It, It2>(source1, source2, size);
}  

template<typename It1, typename It2> typename DotProduct<It1,It2>::Result   dotProduct(It1 source1, It2 source2, const size_t size) 
{   
  typedef typename DotProduct<It1,It2>::Result Result;   
  return dotProductRCtItIt2<Result, Result, It1, It2>(source1, source2, size);
}

template<typename R, typename Ct, typename It, typename It2> R dotProduct(It source, It2 source2, const size_t size)
{
 return dotProductRCtItIt2<R, Ct, It, It2>(source, source2, size);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{   
  const char *s1 = "abc";   
  const char *s2 = "def";   
  cerr << dotProduct<int>(s1,s2,3) << "\n";   
  cerr << dotProduct(s1,s2,3) << "\n";   
  return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: Make it an http://sscce.org, please. I'm sure you can minimize your example code. Also, what are the errors?

Comment: Error is cannot instantiate std::iterator_traits<int>::value_type in that dotProduct()

Comment: which compiler? it does sound like a bug (as Tomek said)

Comment: gcc version 4.6.0 (does not compile), VS2005 compiler (compiles)

Comment: Just another question is whether according to standard this code is correct or not? And if it's not correct according to standard do I have any other way how to achieve the automatic return type resolution?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::enable_if` instead of your own implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing int type to iterator_traits. iterator_traits template will only work with pointers and classes which expose appropriate typedefs.

Now, why the compiler throws an error when going through the first overload is not clear for me, especially that this overload is incorrect for the calls you are making. I would say it looks like a bug in a compiler but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: SFINAE mechanism should hide the intantiation of std::iterator_traits<int>::value_type - that's why there is DotProduct and DetermineSingleType classes - the class typedef cannot be done to non-existing type and therefore instantiation of DotProduct class and/or DetermineSingleType should fail - and SFINAE should then remove the dotProduct with single source param out of overload resolution set (not include it to that set at all). This is correctly happening with dotProduct 2 source params versions. There must be something else. Strangely this compiles ok on VS2005.

Comment: Also note that when it tries to match dotProduct<int> then it must also try it with template <typename It> typename DetermineSingleType<It>::Result dotProduct(It source, const size_t size); method as it's valid candidate from the point of template instantiation resolution.

Comment: Why do you think dotProduct(It source, const size_t size) is valid candidate? The error pointed me to the line with dotProduct<int>(s1,s2,3) which obviously takes 3 parameters. What I think is that the fact you specified the first template parameter somehow confused the compiler to include the above method in its list of possible overloads which IMHO is wrong.

Comment: It's from C++ standard all the template function with same name are considered as candidates.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the result type determination classes need to be dependent on the function parameters. One solution looks like to "misuse" const size_t size parameter for this:

template  typename DetermineSingleType::value_type dotProduct(It source, St size) {
 ... 
}

For the call:
dotProduct((char *) s1, 3);

This way the resulting type determination cannot be run until the type of St is determined, therefore the parameter matching procedure starts to match used parameters with template types and that fails since implicit conversion from char* to int is not possible.

However the bad thing about this solution is that the const size_t size parameter must be templatized and misused. Adding another dummy parameter with default value doesn't prevent the compilation error.

Currently I don't know of any other better solution and solution with misusing size parameter is not any nice one. Therefore most likely I'll have to give up on automatic return type determination. Any other ideas?